# Is there a site dedicated to elementary compatible apps and themes?

Tags: applications, themes

I'm not referring to [Gnome Look](http://gnomelook.org), but an equivalent. Is there a similar site that only lists apps and themes for elementary OS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few websites

- [Apps for elementary](http://quassy.github.io/elementary-apps/apps/)
- [Made for elementary](http://madeforelementary.tumblr.com/)
- [lme Linux](http://lmelinux.net/apps-made-for-elementary-os/)
- [Elementary OS Freya – Apps & tweaks](https://allienworks.net/2015/elementary-os-freya-apps-tweaks/)

Comment: [Webby](https://quassy.github.io/elementary-apps/Webby/) ppa is not working in Loki.

Answer (score 0):

As a complement/update **for Loki** to the other answer which redirects to sites like "Apps for Elementary" I want to keep an update on this, gradually adding here some info on the apps that I test.

There are these reviews on some of the apps on Youtube: [Elementary 3rd Party Apps Reviews](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLyYtzGEu4xnGRga7Rvj76h4UuNinUP4j0).

But that review, as well as the linked addresses seem to be from the Freya period.

In Loki some of the apps are now default, like **Calculator**, or are very commonly used, like **Tweaks**.

---

[**Webby**](https://quassy.github.io/elementary-apps/Webby/), the web app browser, has a ppa that doesn't work in Loki.

---

[**Translator**](https://quassy.github.io/elementary-apps/Translator/) is meant for translating text between seven languages, works in Loki. Also includes a dictionary.

[image]

The translation engine it Yandex, not as good as Google Translate, at least for now.

---

[**Hourglass**](https://quassy.github.io/elementary-apps/Hourglass/) works fine; it includes alarm, timer and stopwatch.

[image]